# Make the pattern of a \def depend on another macro

Tags: macros, expansion, programming

I would like to set up a macro defined something like this:

```
\def\processline string: #1.#2\relax{\gdef\errorline{#1}}
```

The catch is that the string should be given by the contents of another macro.  I tried to do this using `\expandafter`s, and it resulted in an error. (Note that the code below is saved in a file named `errortest.tex`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\edef\filename{\jobname-funny_name}
\def\processline errortest-funny_name.asy: #1.#2\relax{\gdef\errorline{#1}}
% The following line does not work:
%\expandafter\def\expandafter\processline\filename.asy: #1.#2\relax{\gdef\errorline{#1}}
\edef\oneline{errortest-funny_name.asy: 5.6 syntax error}
{\expandafter\processline\oneline\relax}

\begin{document}
stuff

\errorline
\end{document}
```

Why does this fail?  How can it be made to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a category code problem, `\jobname` does not produce normal category codes when expanded. You can get around it by using `\scantokens`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\filename{\scantokens\expandafter{\jobname\noexpand}-funny_name}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\processline\filename.asy: #1.#2\relax{\gdef\errorline{#1}}
\edef\oneline{errortest-funny_name.asy: 5.6 syntax error}
{\expandafter\processline\oneline\relax}

\begin{document}
stuff

\errorline
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can also use `\filename` directly in the definition of `\oneline` (this will have the advantage of allowing more exotic characters in the processed filenames):

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\filename{\jobname-funny_name}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\processline\filename.asy: #1.#2\relax{\gdef\errorline{#1}}
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\oneline\expandafter{\filename.asy: 5.6 syntax error}
{\expandafter\processline\oneline\relax}

\begin{document}
stuff

\errorline
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your second suggestion won't work for me because `\oneline` is actually a line read from an error log file, but the first suggestion is exactly what I need.